# Sencha extjs datefield. Clicking today button has different behavior than selecting a date

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a date field with the following configuration:

```
 xtype: "datefield",
 itemId: "dpaToPicker",
 editable: false,
 value: new Date(),
 maxValue: new Date(),
 hideMode: 'display',
 fieldCls: 'smallFont',
 fieldStyle: 'border:0; background:none',
 frame: false,
```

The issue I am having is that when I select a particular day from the picker, I get the picker closing and the day is set correctly, and focus seems to be back on the date field as expected.
However when I select the "Today" button, there seems to be a different behavior, the picker closes and the date is set correctly on the date field, but focus does not seem to be set and bubbled events occur that causes my container to close.
Is there some way I can stop the bubbling and perhaps force the focus?

Comment: What exact version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Its 6.0.1 Classic, thanks

Comment: `bubbled events occur that causes my container to close` could you explain which container is closing ? or try to create [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle)